# I want to insert random gender(M or F) values into a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(Email varchar2(30) CONSTRAINT UserKey PRIMARY KEY,
 First_Name varchar2(30),
 Last_Name varchar2(30),
 Password varchar2(15),
 Date_of_Birth date,
 Age integer,
 Gender varchar2(1) CONSTRAINT UserGender CHECK (Gender in ('M', 'F', 'f', 'm')),
 Phone_num number(14));
```

This is the schema that i am using. I just want to update the gender column randomly with values M/F. Can someone help me out with the query?

[image: Table looks like this]

Comment: Very bad practice. Decide on lower/upper case and stick to it. (M/F or m/f, not both)

Answer (score 5):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE Users
SET Gender = CASE WHEN ROUND(dbms_random.value()) = 0
                  THEN 'M'
                  ELSE 'F' END
```

**Explanation:**

Oracle's [`dbms_random.value()`](http://lhttps://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i999084) function returns a decimal number in the range `[0,1)`.  Hence, half the time we can expect this number rounded to zero decimal places to equal 0, the other half rounding to 1.  In the `CASE` expression used above, we therefore randomly assign male gender half the time and female gender the other half of the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for a modification of the dbms_random.value() but couldn't figure it out. This worked like a charm. :)